# Pegar conteúdo de dentro de uma div e colocar no content de uma meta tag

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um site antigo, feito todo em html, com milhares de páginas para editar. Todas as páginas de notícias, estão com o mesmo título

```
<title>Prefeitura Municipal...</title>
```

E na época não inseri as meta tags que o Facebook lê. 
Gostaria então de inserir esse código abaixo em todas as páginas

```
<meta property="og:title" content="">
```

e que dentro do "content" ficasse o próprio título da notícia.
Tenho uma div de título, exemplo:

```
<span id="titulo">Título da notícia</span>
```

Gostaria de "pegar" esse conteúdo de dentro dessa div e replicar ele dentro do "content". De forma meio automática, que funcionasse em todas as milhares de notícias.

Detalhe, todas as páginas estão em .html, se estivessem em .php poderia ser mais simples resolver isso, mas não posso mudá-las para .php. Tentei mudar o título via javascript, como mostro abaixo. E muda certinho, mas o Facebook não reconhece essa mudança, e continua mantendo o que está no código.

```
document.title = $('#titulo').html()
```

Comment: O Facebook não vai pegar o valor de um elemento alterado via JavaScript. Ele pega o que retorna do servidor. O JavaScript é executado no navegador. Creio que você terá que arrumar uma forma automática de alterar os arquivos, já que são muitos e fazer isso manualmente seria inviável.

Comment: @Sam Isso, estou tentando encontrar uma forma automática, consigo inserir de forma automatizada um mesmo código em todos via Dreamweaver, mas inserir o título manualmente em cada um seria impossível mesmo.

Comment: Talvez com uma aplicação em PHP vc consiga reescrever cada arquivo inserindo a tag com o respectivo título.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o *crawler* lê o HTML antes de executar o Script, ainda mais um em jQuery que o browser tem que indexar a lib externa e depois rodar tudo etc. Por isso, talvez o FaceBook não esteja reconhecendo a mudança de valor.

De qq forma o seu Script está pegando o texto do `span` e colocando na tag `title` do `head`, e não na `metatag` correto como deveria.

Para colocar o texto do `span` dentro da `metatag` vc pode fazer como abaixo.

```js
let tit = document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML;

let meta = document.querySelector('[property="og:title"]');

meta.setAttribute('content', tit);

console.log(meta);
```

```html
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="">
</head>

<span id="titulo">Título da notícia</span>
```

---

**EDIT**

Se vc não tem a `metatag` inserida no documento vc primeiro precisa cria-la dentro do `<head>` e depois inserir o conteúdo com o texto do título. Como isso vai ser feito depois que a página é carregada não posso garantir que o FaceBook vai reconhecer esse conteúdo injetado...

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += '<meta property="og:title" content="">';

let tit = document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML;

let meta = document.querySelector('[property="og:title"]');

meta.setAttribute('content', tit);

console.log(meta);
```

```html
<span id="titulo">Título da notícia</span>
```

Comment: eu não entendo muito de javascript, mas está me apontando um erro de sintaxe, o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Podem ser várias coisas. Mas esse script deve vir no final da página, deve ser a última coisa antes do </body>, além disso, vc tem que ter uma tag com o `id="titulo"` na página, e no seu <head> vc tb tem que ter a tag `<meta property="og:title" content="">` é nela que o script vai inserir o texto que está na tag com `id="titulo"`

Comment: @Camila se o seu documento não tem a metatag do faceboock vc tem que cria-la com o script, e depois pegar o título e colocar como conteúdo. se for esse o caso me fala que edito a resposta. Leia o **EDIT** que deixei na resposta

Comment: Sim, havia colocado isso no head. Um código assim o Dreamweaver reconhece como erro de sintaxe:
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Título da página</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="">
</head>
<body>
<span id="titulo">Aqui o titulo da notícia</span>
<script>
let tit = document.getElementById('titulo').innerHTML;
let meta = document.querySelector('[property="og:title"]');
meta.setAttribute('content', tit);
console.log(meta);
</script>
</body>
</html>
e se publico, ocorre a mesma coisa que antes, dá certo, mas o Facebook ñ reconhece.

Comment: @Camila deve ter alguma config no DW que mostra erro por algum motivo, mas se vc testar direto no browser vai ver que no console não acusa erro. Sobre o Facebook, vc pode aguardar uns dias para ver se atualiza as informações, e se não atualizar é pelo motivo que ja comentamos aqui, o FB não reconhece dados alterados no DOM, só reconhece o que é entregue na solicitação e não depois que a página é carregada